# Manual request dispatch in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I need create request on rails application in application itself.

Something like this (pseudo-code)

```
def some_method()
    clone_request = request.clone
    request.url = "some/url/"
    result_html = Rails.application.run(request)
    # ...
end
```

Rails version 3.2.8

Is this even possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `app.get("/some/url/")` to generate a request. Then, run `app.request` to get the request data, `app.response` for the response, and `app.response.body` for the html.

If you need to authenticate, run this first (modify for however you login):
    `app.post("/session", :email => "email@host.com", :password => "******")`

If you need additional instances:
    `app2 = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)`

Comment: Thank you. And if I need the current request env?

Comment: Do you mean `app.request.env`?

Comment: You have incomming request by ajax for example and `request.env` contains some data about session.